# Permissões para um USER Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Estou criando um usuário Oracle para o meu banco, após definir o básico tentei executar meu script para criar as `tabelas` e `sequences`, porém, a ferramenta me retornou um erro dizendo faltar permissões.

o erro:

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-01031: privilégios insuficientes
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Eu defini as seguistes permissões:

Edit: (erro persiste)

```
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TABLE, CREATE SESSION, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE, SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES,  ALTER, INDEX, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA TO Aluno;
```

Quais permissões seriam necessárias (que me faltam) para criar as sequences, tabelas e demais atividades básicas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So usar `GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO Aluno;`

Comment: Puts! Obrigado, deu certíssimo, me matei achando que era algo bem mais complexo !

Answer (score 0):

> GRANT PROCEDURE, **CREAT**, DROP, ALTER, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA TO Aluno;

Bem o que falta é o CREATE mesmo.

```
GRANT PROCEDURE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA TO Aluno;
```

Tente neste formato, acho que você só esqueceu um **"E"** no CREATE.

Dê um revoke:

```
REVOKE PROCEDURE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA FROM Aluno;
```

E novamente dê as instruções corretas, lembre-se que o REVOKE QUE DEI É NO **CREAT** também.

```
GRANT PROCEDURE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA TO Aluno;
```

Comment: e como faço pra alterar agora que ja foi criado ?

Comment: tente utilizar GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA To Aluno;

Comment: não, isso não funciona

Comment: Editei, veja se agora você consegue. Se não, algo errado não está certo. HEHEHHE abraços amigo.

Comment: ORA-00990: privilégio não encontrado ou inválido
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Normalmente é erro de sintaxe isso, estranho. Você não fez nada além do que postou? Se não tente tirar o CREATE do REVOKE. Isso está muito estranho, infelizmente não estou com o SGBD para testar aqui.

Comment: você sabe como dropar o usuário ?

Comment: DROP USER Aluno CASCADE; 

Use a CASCADE para limpar em cascata inclusive os objetos do usuario. Cuidado

Comment: Deu certo, ai eu criei denovo, inclusive corrigi o CREATE, porém, ele ainda da erro dizendo que faltam permissoes

Comment: dei um select nas permissoes ele me mostrou so CREATE SESSION e UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, o que falta ?