# USUARIOS ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Boa tarde.
Eu tenho dois owners no meu oracle 
exemplo o Owner "X" e o outro owner "Y". Onde cada um tem suas tabelas próprias,
mas eu quero que o owner "X" consiga dar update, insert e delete em algumas tabelas do owner "Y".
E possível?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Permissões para um USER Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222036/permiss%c3%b5es-para-um-user-oracle), relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235802/grant-para-varias-tabelas-oracle

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível! É necessário conceder([GRANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html)) as devidas permissões para o USER/ROLE.

Para criar a permissão específica para tabela seria utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON Y.TABELA to X
```